# Setting up MAC filter in Binatone ADSL DT 845W

Tags: wireless-networking, adsl-router, adsl2+

How do I restrict the wi-fi usage to a particular set of MAC addresses in a Binatone ADSL2+ Router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to interface setup -> Wireless

set the wireless mac filter to active, set the action to 'Allow association' and list the Mac addresses you want to allow access. Click save.